# How to infer type of instance to use as field type (using interface merging)?

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, instance, type-inference

I need to write definition file for external library. I augment class using interface merging and there are cases when field of library class is of the same type as the instance itself. Demo code:

```
// Augmentation
declare global {
    interface Class<T = any> {
        doesntInfer: T;
        infersFine(this: T): T;
    }

    class Class {}
}
```

But when I try to use it, method return type is inferred correctly, but field is still typeof any:

```
public test(arg: Class) {
    arg.infersFine().infersFine().infersFine(); // works, infersFine() return type is Class
    arg.doesntInfer.; // doesn't work, type == any
}
```

If there was no interface merging, I'd simply do this:

```
class Class {
    public doesntInfer: this;
    public infersFine(): this;
}
```

But I can't use `this` in interface declaration. I also don't want to simply use `Class` instead of `T`, because I want to be able to use inheritance.
Is it even possible?

P.S. I do interface merging because declaration is split in two files: 
1) Ambient d.ts with class and export declaration 
2) Moduled d.ts (which uses imports from other libraries), where augmenting interface is declared.

Comment: But you can use `this` inside the interface... and it seems to work fine with merging ...

Comment: Oops, my bad :) I thought I tried it and it didn't work, but apparently, it works, thank you)

Answer (score 0):

As Titian Cernicova-Dragomir pointed out, you actually CAN use `this` in interface, so

```
interface Class {
    doesntInfer: this;
    infersFine(): this;
}
```

works as intended.